# Url dinamic assume user logado na visuzaliação

Tags: django, django-2.0

tenho um sistema que quando o usuario está logado no menu superior que é fixo aparece a foto e nome dele, mais as opções já que ele está logado, até ai tudo bem.
e estou usando as url dinamicas para fazer exemplo, www.mysite.com.br/usuario
para que você estando ou nao logado possa ver os perfis do usuario, porém, quando digito essa url dinamica, ela mostra o usuario e troca automaticamente o menu superior que estava logado o usuario, pelo usuario da pagina visitada.
digamos que meu nome de usuario é Mauricio, estou logado e lá em cima aparece minha foto e meu nome e vou ver o perfil do usuario Roger, quando vizualizo o perfil do roger, meu login lá em cima passa para o do roger automaticamente, e não sei como resolver isso
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_text
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from .tokens import account_activation_token
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from sistema.tokens import account_activation_token
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site


from .models import (
    Usuario, 
    Negocio
)

from .forms import (
    UsuarioForm, 
    NegocioForm
)

def profile_detail(request, username):
    if User.objects.get(username=username):
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        return render(request, "profile.html", {
            "user": user,
        })
    else:
        return render("User not found")


def index(request):
    usuario = Usuario.objects.all()
    form = UsuarioForm()
    data = {'usuario': usuario, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'index.html', data)

def perfil(request):
    usuario = Usuario.objects.all()
    form = UsuarioForm()
    data = {'usuario': usuario, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'perfil.html', data)



def cadastro(request):
    usuario = Usuario.objects.all()
    form = UsuarioForm()
    data = {'usuario': usuario, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'cadastro.html', data)

def cadastro_novo(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UsuarioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.usuario.nome = form.cleaned_data.get('nome')
            user.usuario.sobrenome = form.cleaned_data.get('sobrenome')
            user.usuario.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user.usuario.telefone = form.cleaned_data.get('telefone')
            user.usuario.cidade = form.cleaned_data.get('cidade')
            user.usuario.endereco = form.cleaned_data.get('endereco')
            user.usuario.cpf = form.cleaned_data.get('cpf')
            user.usuario.numero = form.cleaned_data.get('numero')
            user.usuario.bairro = form.cleaned_data.get('bairro')
            user.usuario.cep = form.cleaned_data.get('cep')
            user.usuario.password1 = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user.usuario.data_nascimento = form.cleaned_data.get('data_nascimento')
            user.usuario.pet = form.cleaned_data.get('pet')
            user.usuario.foto = form.cleaned_data.get('foto')
            user.usuario.sexo = form.cleaned_data.get('sexo')
            user.usuario.estado = form.cleaned_data.get('estado')
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Ative seu registro no PetAqui'
            message = render_to_string('account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)
            return redirect('account_activation_sent')
    else:
        form = UsuarioForm()
    return render(request, 'cadastro.html', {'form': form})


def account_activation_sent(request):
    return render(request, 'account_activation_sent.html')


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.usuario.email_confirmed = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        # return redirect('home')
        return render(request, 'account_activation.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'account_activation_invalid.html')

def cadastro_negocio(request):
    negocio = Negocio.objects.all()
    form = NegocioForm()
    data = {'negocio': negocio, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'cadastro_negocio.html', data)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile
from django.core.mail import send_mail
import math
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from stdimage.models import StdImageField

STATE_CHOICES = (
    ('AC', 'Acre'), ('AL', 'Alagoas'), ('AP', 'Amapá'),
    ('AM', 'Amazonas'), ('BA', 'Bahia'), ('CE', 'Ceará'),
    ('DF', 'Distrito Federal'), ('ES', 'Espírito Santo'),
    ('GO', 'Goiás'), ('MA', 'Maranhão'), ('MT', 'Mato Grosso'),
    ('MS', 'Mato Grosso do Sul'), ('MG', 'Minas Gerais'),
    ('PA', 'Pará'), ('PB', 'Paraíba'), ('PR', 'Paraná'),
    ('PE', 'Pernambuco'), ('PI', 'Piauí'), ('RJ', 'Rio de Janeiro'),
    ('RN', 'Rio Grande do Norte'), ('RS', 'Rio Grande do Sul'),
    ('RO', 'Rondônia'), ('RR', 'Roraima'), ('SC', 'Santa Catarina'),
    ('SP', 'São Paulo'), ('SE', 'Sergipe'), ('TO', 'Tocantins')
)

cat = 'https://www.petz.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/gato02.jpg'
gato = 'https://www.petz.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/gato02.jpg'
PET_CHOICES = (
    ('dog', 'Cachorro'), ('cat', 'Gato'), ('bird', 'Pássaros'), ('fish', 'Peixes'), ('rep', 'Reptéis'),
    ('horse', 'Cavalos'), ('rat', 'Roedores')
)

SEXO_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Masculino'), ('F', 'Feminino')
)


class Usuario(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    foto = StdImageField(blank=False, variations={
        'large': (600, 400),
        'thumbnail': (100, 100, True),
        'medium': (300, 200),
    })
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, verbose_name="Celular")
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=19)
    data_nascimento = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=False, verbose_name="Data de nascimento")
    sexo = models.CharField(default='M', max_length=2, choices=SEXO_CHOICES)
    pet = MultiSelectField(max_length=30, choices=PET_CHOICES, verbose_name="Selecione seus pets")
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    bairro = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    cep = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    estado = models.CharField(default='RS', max_length=3, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def cadastro_novo(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Usuario.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.usuario.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nome) + ' - ' + str(self.email) + ' - ' + str(self.telefone)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

cat = 'https://www.petz.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/gato02.jpg'
gato = 'https://www.petz.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/gato02.jpg'
PET_CHOICES = (
    ('dog', 'Cachorro'), ('cat', 'Gato'), ('bird', 'Pássaros'), ('fish', 'Peixes'), ('rep', 'Reptéis'),
    ('horse', 'Cavalos'), ('rat', 'Roedores')
)

STATE_CHOICES = (
    ('AC', 'Acre'), ('AL', 'Alagoas'), ('AP', 'Amapá'),
    ('AM', 'Amazonas'), ('BA', 'Bahia'), ('CE', 'Ceará'),
    ('DF', 'Distrito Federal'), ('ES', 'Espírito Santo'),
    ('GO', 'Goiás'), ('MA', 'Maranhão'), ('MT', 'Mato Grosso'),
    ('MS', 'Mato Grosso do Sul'), ('MG', 'Minas Gerais'),
    ('PA', 'Pará'), ('PB', 'Paraíba'), ('PR', 'Paraná'),
    ('PE', 'Pernambuco'), ('PI', 'Piauí'), ('RJ', 'Rio de Janeiro'),
    ('RN', 'Rio Grande do Norte'), ('RS', 'Rio Grande do Sul'),
    ('RO', 'Rondônia'), ('RR', 'Roraima'), ('SC', 'Santa Catarina'),
    ('SP', 'São Paulo'), ('SE', 'Sergipe'), ('TO', 'Tocantins')
)
SEXO_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Masculino'), ('F', 'Feminino')
)


class UsuarioForm(UserCreationForm):
    nome = forms.CharField()
    sobrenome = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Sobrenome'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Email Válido', 'id': 'email'}))
    email2 = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Repita seu email', 'id': 'email2'}))
    cpf = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': '000.000.000-00', 'class': 'cpf'}))
    telefone = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': '(00)0000-0000', 'class': 'phone_with_ddd'}))
    cidade = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Sua cidade'}))
    endereco = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Rua, Av, Estrada'}))
    numero = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'numero', 'class': 'numero'}))
    bairro = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'seu bairro'}))
    cep = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': '00000-000', 'class': 'cep'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Mínimo 8 digitos', 'id': 'password1'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Mínimo 8 digitos', 'id': 'password2', 'label': 'Repita a senha'}))
    data_nascimento = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': '00/00/000', 'class': 'data'}))
    pet = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=PET_CHOICES)
    foto = forms.FileField(
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': 'False'}))
    sexo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SEXO_CHOICES)
    estado = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATE_CHOICES)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UsuarioForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["password1"].label = "Repita a senha"
        self.fields["password2"].label = "Repita o email"
        # pode fazer isso com todos os campos

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username', 'email', 'email2', 'telefone', 'data_nascimento',
            'sexo', 'foto', 'endereco', 'numero', 'bairro',
            'cidade', 'estado', 'cep', 'pet'
        )
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from .views import (
    index,
    cadastro,
    cadastro_novo,
    cadastro_negocio,
    activate,
    account_activation_sent,
    perfil,
    profile_detail

)

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^index/$', index, name='sistema_index'),
  url(r'^cadastro/$', cadastro, name='sistema_cadastro'),
  url(r'perfil/$', perfil, name='sistema_perfil'),
  url(r'^cadastro-novo/$', cadastro_novo, name='sistema_cadastro_novo'),
  url(r'^cadastro-negocio/$', cadastro_negocio, name='sistema_cadastro_negocio'),
  url(r'^account_activation_sent/$', views.account_activation_sent, name='account_activation_sent'),
  url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$', views.profile_detail, name='sistema_profile'),
  path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.activate, name='activate'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

profile.html

```
{%extends 'bases/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block main %}
{{usuario.id}}
<div class="card text-white bg-primary">
    <div class="card-header">
        <p class="card-text">
            <small class="text-muted">
                <a href="{% url 'sistema_index' %}" class="text-white ">Home /</a>
                <a class="text-white">Perfil </a>
            </small>
            </a></p>
        {{ user.usuario.nome }} {{ user.usuario.sobrenome }}{{ user.usuario.id }}
    </div>
    <div class="card title  ">
        <div class="card-body text-secondary">
            {{ user.usuario.nome}}
            <img src="{{ user.usuario.foto.medium.url}}" class="rounded-circle" width="150" height="150">
            {{ user.usuario.cpf}}
            {{ user}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock main %}
```

menu

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mensagens |</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <img src="{{ user.usuario.foto.thumbnail.url}}" class="rounded-circle" width="35" height="35">
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
               aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <img src="{% static 'svg/settings.svg' %}" width="20" height="20" alt="">{{user}} |
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ver perfil</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Avaliações</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configurações</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}"><img src="{% static 'svg/log-out.svg' %}" width="20"
                                                                        height="20" alt="">Sair</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm" href="{% url 'sistema_cadastro_negocio' %}" role="button"> Cadastre
                seu negócio </a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <form class="form-inline">

            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" href="{% url 'sistema_cadastro' %}" role="button">
                Cadastre-se </a>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{% url 'login' %}" role="button"> Entrar </a>
    </div>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Aparentemente em view.profile_detail você está retornando "user" que acaba se confundindo com o usuario logado user que carrega as infos no header, não?

Comment: na view profile_detail troque o "user" para "user_detail" e no template profile.html também, acho que assim o usuario deste contexto não vai se confundir com o usuário logado.

Comment: Ficou perfeito obrigado!!!!